# On click of a button in Salesforce i need to open a new mail in outlook?

Tags: apex, email

I have a requirement where in On click of a button in Salesforce i need to open a new mail in outlook? Is this Possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom button with a URL type and simply use a mailto: link.

e.g. If you were creating the button on Lead use: mailto:{!Lead.Email}

This will open in your default email client, be it Mac Mail, Outlook or whatever.